# Context.io PHP API Giving Error

Tags: php, contextio

I have run into a problem with the Context.io API. I keep getting the following error message:

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/nginx/html/custom-assets/includes/ContextIO/demo.php on line 11`

Here is my php code:

```
// Require the Context.io PHP Library
require('class.contextio.php');

// See https://console.context.io/#settings to get your consumer key and consumer secret.
$contextIO = new ContextIO('consumer key','consumer secret');
$accountId = 'xxxxxxxxxx'; // Account ID of email account

$args = array('folder' => 'Inbox', 'include_flags' => 1, 'include_thread_size' => 1, 'include_body' => 1, 'limit' => 50);
echo "Getting last 50 messages...<br><br>";
$r = $contextIO->listMessages($accountId, $args);
if ($r !== false) {
    foreach ($r->getData() as $message) {
        echo "Subject: ".$message['subject']."<br>";
    }
} else {
    var_dump($r);
}
```

I have no clue why this is not working. Anybody have any clue why?

Answer (score 0):

All of the functions in the ContextIO library return a ContextIOResponse object, or false if the API returns an http error code. If you add a check for `if($r !== false)` before you call `getData()` it should catch any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried doing what you suggested. I have updated my original posting with my newest code. The `var_dump($r)` prints this to the screen: `bool(false)`. Do you happen to have any ideas on what may be causing this? When I run this command with the same parameters set in the API Console on context.io, the results are returned. Thanks.

Comment: Also, just FYI, the email address I am testing against is a gmail account. I also have an AOL email address I use for testing. When I use the account ID for the AOL email address, the php script prints the subjects without any errors. However, my two gmail accounts are not working.

Comment: Can you email us at support@context.io? My guess is there's an email in the list with problematic data that is causing the return to fail.